# Accordion menu with mat-list-item is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm working on a Angular 9 web with many modules and submodules. The thing is I need to implement a menu with the modules and childs using accordion strcuture. Also I'm using material desigin and I need to implement this feature with `mat-nav-list`, `mat-list-item` and `a` (I'm not looking a solution with mat-expansion-panel, ul, li, I need a scss solution for mat-list-item)

here is a example template --> https://primer.fusepx.com/angular/

And this image is exactly what I want to do

[image]

I got a previous version of the template in angular 4 and I tried to adapt the styles to my new application, but something went wrong and the style didn't work. This is the result I got:

[image]

the scss for this is quite large and Can't put a demo with stackblitz 'couse many things not working

but basically I am using 3 diferent directives to put the class .open in the menu link and I wonder if there is another easier way to do this kind of menu using mat-nav-list, mat-list-item and the directives

**DIRECTIVES**

**ACCORDION DIRECTIVE**

```
import { Directive, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/operators';

import { AccordionLinkDirective } from './accordionlink.directive';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAccordion]',
})
export class AccordionDirective implements AfterContentChecked {

protected navlinks: Array<AccordionLinkDirective> = [];

closeOtherLinks(openLink: AccordionLinkDirective): void {
  this.navlinks.forEach((link: AccordionLinkDirective) => {
    if (link !== openLink) {
      link.open = false;
    }
  });
}

addLink(link: AccordionLinkDirective): void {
  this.navlinks.push(link);
}

removeGroup(link: AccordionLinkDirective): void {
  const index = this.navlinks.indexOf(link);
  if (index !== -1) {
    this.navlinks.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

checkOpenLinks() {
  this.navlinks.forEach((link: AccordionLinkDirective) => {
    if (link.group) {
      const routeUrl = this.router.url;
      const currentUrl = routeUrl.split('/');
      if (currentUrl.indexOf( link.group ) > 0) {
        link.open = true;
        this.closeOtherLinks(link);
      }
    }
  });
}

ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe(e => this.checkOpenLinks());
  // this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(e => this.checkOpenLinks());
}

constructor( private router: Router) {
  setTimeout(() => this.checkOpenLinks());
}
}
```

**Accordion Link Directive**

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Inject, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AccordionDirective } from './accordion.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAccordionLink]'
})
export class AccordionLinkDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() public group: any;

  @HostBinding('class.open')
  @Input()
  get open(): boolean {
    return this._open;
  }

  set open(value: boolean) {
    this._open = value;
    if (value) { this.nav.closeOtherLinks(this); }
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  protected _open: boolean;
  protected nav: AccordionDirective;

  constructor(@Inject(AccordionDirective) nav: AccordionDirective) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.nav.addLink(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): any {
    this.nav.removeGroup(this);
  }

  toggle(): any {
    this.open = !this.open;
  }
}
```

**Accordion Anchor Directive**

```
  import { Directive, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AccordionLinkDirective } from './accordionlink.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAccordionToggle]'
})
export class AccordionAnchorDirective {

  protected navlink: AccordionLinkDirective;

  constructor( @Inject(AccordionLinkDirective) navlink: AccordionLinkDirective) {
    this.navlink = navlink;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e: any) {
    this.navlink.toggle();
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="app">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened color="primary" class="sidenav dark sidebar-panel app-inner">
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon class="material-icons-round">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- MENU /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->


    <mat-nav-list appAccordion class="navigation navlist" role="list">
        <mat-list-item appAccordionLink *ngFor="let menuitem of menu" [group]="menuitem.state" class="module-link" role="listitem">

            <!-- LINK  -->
            <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" [id]="menuitem.state" [routerLink]="['/', menuitem.state]"
                *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuitem.iconType==='icon'" class="material-icons-round">{{ menuitem.icon }}
                </mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuitem.iconType==='svg'"><svg class="svg-24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="currentColor" [attr.d]="menuitem.icon" /></svg></mat-icon>
                <span>{{ menuitem.name }}</span>
                <span fxFlex></span>
              </span>
            </a>

            <!-- SUB LINK  -->
            <a appAccordionToggle class="relative" [id]="menuitem.state" href="javascript:;"
                *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'sub'">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuitem.iconType==='icon'" class="material-icons-round">{{ menuitem.icon }}
                </mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="menuitem.iconType==='svg'"><svg class="svg-24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="currentColor" [attr.d]="menuitem.icon" /></svg></mat-icon>
                <span>{{ menuitem.name}}</span>
                <span fxFlex></span>
                <span class="menu-badge mat-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span>
                <mat-icon class="menu-caret">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
            </a>
            <mat-nav-list class="sub-menu" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'sub'">
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let childitem of menuitem.children" routerLinkActive="open">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/', childitem.state ]" class="relative">
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="childitem.iconType==='icon'" class="material-icons-round">
                            {{ childitem.icon }}</mat-icon>
                        <mat-icon *ngIf="childitem.iconType==='svg'"><svg class="svg-24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="currentColor" [attr.d]="childitem.icon" /></svg></mat-icon>
                        <span>{{ childitem.name }}</span>
                    </a>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-nav-list>

        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>

</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
    Content
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

**SCSS**

My SCSS is to large ---- download the file here ---> https://github.com/Chej0/accordion-style

Comment: Firstly, please consider _copying and pasting_ your code into the question itself instead of providing screenshots of your code as it may not be easily readable or may not load for users with poor internet connections. Secondly, please consider providing a GitHub Gist instead of a download to a suspicious-looking URL for your SCSS file.

Comment: @Edric thank you very much for your feedback. I just updated the info with your suggestions

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your the  scss [right here in yellow](https://github.com/Chej0/accordion-style/blob/42c0d0f2ead8412d4a28d5efe2b42e6142af515e/styles.scss#L953). If I understand it correctly, you just used `display:block`  instead of `display:flex`